# how to transform a data special structure to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my problem is simple. I get from internet data that looks like this:

```
[{"key":"1","title":"Monétaire",
"children":[{"key":"4","title":"Monétaire Europe",
"children":[{"key":"1","title":"Monétaire euro"}, 
{"key":"2","title":"Monétaire euro dynamique"}, 
{"key":"3","title":"Monétaire autre devise Europe"}]},
{"key":"5","title":"Monétaire hors Europe",
"children":[{"key":"4","title":"Monétaire USD"},
{"key":"5","title":"Monétaire hors Europe autre devise"}]}]}
```

The code to get the data is:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche' 
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = soup.find(class_='quantatree-datasource')['value']
data
```

The pandas I would like to get is:

```
Monétaire     
Monétaire     Monétaire Europe
Monétaire     Monétaire Europe   Monétaire Euro
Monétaire     Monétaire Europe   Monétaire euro dynamique
Monétaire     Monétaire Europe   Monétaire autre devise Europe
Monétaire     Monétaire hors Europe
Monétaire     Monétaire hors Europe.  Monétaire USD
Monétaire     Monétaire hors Europe  Monétaire hors Europe autre devise
```

And I would like to transform this into a pandas dataframe.
How should I do ?

Comment: Into which exact dataframe?

Comment: Please could you add an example of what the output dataframe would look like to your question

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!
As your input is a nested data structure, you have to normalize your input a choice for dataframe. Or share how you want to represent it. pd.json_normalize might be a good approach...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an arbitrarily nested structure with "title" as key of interest and "children" as the nesting object.

You could use a recursive function to help you:

```
def unnest(lst, parents=[], incomplete=True):
    if incomplete and parents:
        yield parents
    for d in lst:
        if 'children' in d:

            yield from unnest(d['children'], parents=parents+[d.get('title')],
                              incomplete=incomplete)
        else:
            yield parents + [d.get('title')]

out = pd.DataFrame(unnest(your_list))
```

Output:

```
           0                      1                                   2
0  Monétaire                   None                                None
1  Monétaire       Monétaire Europe                                None
2  Monétaire       Monétaire Europe                      Monétaire euro
3  Monétaire       Monétaire Europe            Monétaire euro dynamique
4  Monétaire       Monétaire Europe       Monétaire autre devise Europe
5  Monétaire  Monétaire hors Europe                                None
6  Monétaire  Monétaire hors Europe                       Monétaire USD
7  Monétaire  Monétaire hors Europe  Monétaire hors Europe autre devise
```

Variant without incomplete records:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(unnest(your_list, incomplete=False))
print(out)

           0                      1                                   2
0  Monétaire       Monétaire Europe                      Monétaire euro
1  Monétaire       Monétaire Europe            Monétaire euro dynamique
2  Monétaire       Monétaire Europe       Monétaire autre devise Europe
3  Monétaire  Monétaire hors Europe                       Monétaire USD
4  Monétaire  Monétaire hors Europe  Monétaire hors Europe autre devise
```

##### from json

```
# url = 'https://www.quantalys.com/Recherche' 
# soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
# data = soup.find(class_='quantatree-datasource')['value']

import json
out = pd.DataFrame(unnest(json.loads(data), incomplete=True))
```

Output:

```
                  0                      1                              2     3     4
0         Monétaire                   None                           None  None  None
1         Monétaire       Monétaire Europe                           None  None  None
2         Monétaire       Monétaire Europe                 Monétaire euro  None  None
3         Monétaire       Monétaire Europe       Monétaire euro dynamique  None  None
4         Monétaire       Monétaire Europe  Monétaire autre devise Europe  None  None
..              ...                    ...                            ...   ...   ...
222  Eurocroissance         Eurocroissance                           None  None  None
223          Autres                   None                           None  None  None
224          Autres  Fonds de cantonnement                           None  None  None
225          Autres      Devise Long/Short                           None  None  None
226          Autres                 Autres                           None  None  None

[227 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: @jacques [voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) is a privilege that some users have on this platform. Downvoting usually means that a question/answer if of low quality or incorrect. As someone downvoted my answer I asked if there was a reason for it. I could be because something is incorrect (I don't think so). Anyway, don't worry about it. Have you tested my approach? Does it work as you want?

Comment: Yes ! It works fine. Thx